# Return ID if it meet the two condition in same column in a table

Tags: sql

I want to get the members who answers in `cletterdesc` column with `yes` and `Grade I - Grade II`. I tried this query but unlucky:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_answer as a 
    where a.nqid in ('16')
      and a.choice in('29','30','31','32','35','36')
  union
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_answer as b 
    where b.nqid='15'
      and b.choice='21'
) as t
```

[image: tbl_answer]

The `nmemberid`'s answers should meet the two conditions which are `nqid=15` and its `choice=21` and `nqid=16` and its `choice=[29,30,31,32,35,36]`

The marked rows should only be the result and it should be unique based on nmemberid. So, the query should return only two results which are 180 and 174.

Comment: Looking at your results, every row returned matches one of your query predicates. It would seem that you received exactly the rows requested. What is the question/issue? If there are rows missing from the result set you will have to show those to us.

Comment: What is the rows that you mark ? expected results ?

Comment: You have not used cletterdesc in your query.

Comment: Yes, the marked rows should only be the result and it should be unique based on `nmemberid`. So, the query should return only two results which are `180` and `174`.

Comment: @Basilevs Yah, it just the basis. The `nmemberid`'s answers should meet the two conditions which are `nqid=15` and its `choice=21` and `nqid=16` and its `choice=[29,30,31,32,35,36]`

Comment: @SachiTekina, these explanations should've been in question body, not in comments. Please provide complete reasoning for initial query and desired result. Close vote. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To get rows without id duplications one could use GROUP BY directive. You would lose information this way - values in other columns would get smashed in undefined way.